# Pass data Table to controller

Tags: asp.net-core, datatables-1.10

**My Main-View** User_Auth_List.cshtml

```
@model IList<IDESK.Models.UserMaster.ModuleMaster>
@using IDESK.Models.UserMaster;


<!DOCTYPE html>

<div id="modal-placeholder"></div>
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>User_Rights_List</title>
</head>
<form id="frmDetails" asp-action="Create">
<body class="hold-transition sidebar-mini"> 
 
    <div class="wrapper" id="mainbody">
        <h4 style="color:indigo">User Rights Index</h4>
            <button type="button" id="saveButton">Save</button>
        <div class="form-inline" style="margin-top:5px">                
            <label class="col-form-label" style="margin-left:150px; margin-right:15px;color:black;">Select User</label>
            <select class="form-control col-sm-2" style="width: 300px;" id="ddlUser" name="UserId" asp-items="@(new SelectList(ViewBag.UserList, "Value", "Text"))">
            <option value="">-User-</option>
        </select>
        <input type="hidden" name="UserId" />
       </div>
        @*<span asp-validation-for="model => model.UserId" style="margin-left:4px;" class="text-danger"></span>*@
    
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="Create" />
        
        <div id="tblUserAuthDV">
            @await Html.PartialAsync("_TblUser_Auth_List", Model)               
        </div>
 
</div>
    @{
        if (TempData["Message"] != null)
        {
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.Raw(TempData["Alert"])
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    }
 
</body>

    
</form>
</html>

<link href="~/lib/select2/css/select2.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/twitter-bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/select2/js/select2.js"></script>

@section Scripts
    {
    <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function () {

           // $("#tblUserAuthList").DataTable({ stateSave: true, });

            var userid = $(this).find("option:selected").val();

                $("#tblUserAuthDV").hide();

            $('#saveButton').click(function () {
                alert("test");
                var tableData = [];
                $('#tblUserAuthDV table tr').each(function () {
                    var row = $(this);
                    var data = {
                        UserId: row.find('input[name="UserId"]').val(),
                        Module_Group: row.find('input[name="Module_Group"]').val(),
                        ModuleID: row.find('input[name="ModuleID"]').val(),
                        Module_Name: row.find('input[name="Module_Name"]').val(),
                        IsAccess: row.find('input[name="IsAccess"]').val(),
                        IsCreate: row.find('input[name="IsCreate"]').val(),
                        IsDelete: row.find('input[name="IsDelete"]').val(),
                        IsView: row.find('input[name="IsView"]').val(),
                        IsReport: row.find('input[name="IsReport"]').val()
                    };
                    tableData.push(data);
                });

                var formData = {
                    UserId: $('#ddlUser').val(),
                    tableData: tableData
                };

                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("Create", "UserRights")',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: JSON.stringify(formData),
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    success: function (response) {
                        // Handle the success response if needed
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                        console.log(formData);
                        // Handle the error if needed
                    }
                });
            });











            var placeholderElement = $('#modal-placeholder');

            $(document).on('click', 'button[data-bs-toggle="ajax-modal"]', function (event) {
                $("#btnUserRights").html('<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Saving...');
                document.getElementById("btnUserRights").disabled = true;

                var url = $(this).data('url');
                $.get(url).done(function (data) {
                    placeholderElement.html(data);
                    placeholderElement.find('.modal').modal('show');
                    $('.modal').draggable();
                    TouchPopUp();
                });
            });
            placeholderElement.on('click', '[data-bs-dismiss="modal"]', function (event) {
                $("#btnUserRights").html('<i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Save User Rights');
                document.getElementById("btnUserRights").disabled = false;
            });

            placeholderElement.on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
                $("#btnUserRights").html('<i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Save User Rights');
            });
            //alert("site");
            placeholderElement.on('click', '[data-bs-save="modal"]', function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();

                var form = $(this).parents('.modal').find('form');
                var actionUrl = form.attr('action');
                var dataToSend = new FormData(form.get(0));

                $.ajax({ url: actionUrl, method: 'post', data: dataToSend, processData: false, contentType: false }).done(function (data) {
                    var newBody = $('.modal-body', data);
                    placeholderElement.find('.modal-body').replaceWith(newBody);

                    var isValid = newBody.find('[name="IsValid"]').val() === 'True';
                    if (isValid) {
                        var notificationsPlaceholder = $('#notification');
                        var notificationsUrl = notificationsPlaceholder.data('url');
                        $.get(notificationsUrl).done(function (notifications) {
                            notificationsPlaceholder.html(notifications);
                        });

                        var tableElement = $('#tblUserAuthList');
                        var tableUrl = tableElement.data('url');

                        $.get(tableUrl).done(function (table) {
                            tableElement.replaceWith(table);
                        });

                        placeholderElement.find('.modal').modal('hide');
                        alert("Success : Document Saved !");
                    }
                    else {
                        alert("Error : Document did not Save !");
                    }
                    $("#btnUserRights").html('<i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Create User Rights');
                    document.getElementById("btnUserRights").disabled = false;

                });
            });
        })
       
        //----User List
        $('#ddlUser').select2({
            placeholder: "UserId",
            allowClear: true,
            theme: "classic",
            dropdownPosition: 'below'
        });
        $("body").on("change", "#ddlUser", function () {
            $("input[name=UserId]").val($(this).find("option:selected").text());
            var userid = $(this).find("option:selected").val();

            if (userid == "") {
                $("#tblUserAuthDV").hide();
            }
            else {
                $.ajax
                    ({
                        url: '/UserRights/Auth_List',
                        data: { 'id': userid},
                        type: "GET",
                        cache: false,
                        success: function (result) {
                            $("#tblUserAuthDV").html(result)
                        }
                    });
                $("#tblUserAuthDV").show();
            }
        });
            //var IsPallet = $(this).find("option:selected").text().search("True");
    </script>

}
```

**My partialview to generate table : _TblUser_Auth_List.cshtml**

```
@model IEnumerable<IDESK.Models.UserMaster.ModuleMaster>
<table id="tblUserAuthList" class="table table-responsive table-condensed table-fixedheader table-hover" style="table-layout:fixed; width:fit-content; white-space: nowrap; max-height: 500px; margin-top: 10px; "
       data-bs-url="@Url.Action("Auth_List")">
    <thead>

        <tr>          
            <th style="color:white;">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UserId)
            </th>
            <th style="color:white;">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Module_Group)
            </th>
            <th style="color:white;">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ModuleID)
            </th>
            <th style="color:white;">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Module_Name)
            </th>
            <th style="color:white;">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.IsAccess)
            </th>
            <th style="color:white;">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.IsCreate)
            </th>
            <th style="color:white;">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.IsEdit)
            </th>
            <th style="color:white;">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.IsDelete)
            </th>
            <th style="color:white;">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.IsView)
            </th>
            <th style="color:white;">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.IsReport)
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody style="background-color: white;">
            @{

                if (Model != null && Model.Count() > 0 )
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
                    {
                    <tr>
                         <td style="color:black;">

                            @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.ElementAt(i).UserId)
                            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ElementAt(i).UserId)
                        </td>
                        <td style="color:black;">
                            @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.ElementAt(i).Module_Group)
                            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ElementAt(i).Module_Group)
                        </td>
                        <td style="color:black;">
                            @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.ElementAt(i).ModuleID)
                            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ElementAt(i).ModuleID)
                        </td>
                        <td style="color:black;">
                            @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.ElementAt(i).Module_Name)
                            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ElementAt(i).Module_Name)
                        </td>
                        <td style="color:black;">
                            @Html.EditorFor(x => x.ElementAt(i).IsAccess)
                        </td>
                        <td style="color:black;">
                            @Html.EditorFor(x => x.ElementAt(i).IsCreate)
                        </td>
                        <td style="color:black;">
                            @Html.EditorFor(x => x.ElementAt(i).IsEdit)
                        </td>
                        <td style="color:black;">
                            @Html.EditorFor(x => x.ElementAt(i).IsDelete)
                        </td>
                        <td style="color:black;">
                            @Html.EditorFor(x => x.ElementAt(i).IsView)
                        </td>
                        <td style="color:black;">
                            @Html.EditorFor(x => x.ElementAt(i).IsReport)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            }
            }

    </tbody>
</table>




<script type="text/javascript">
    function Save() {

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action("Create")',
            data: $("#frm_User_Auth").serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
                $('.tampil_vr').text(data);
            }
        });
    }
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#tblUserAuthList").DataTable({ stateSave: true, async: false });
       

        
    });
</script>
```

**Controller : UserRightsController.cs**

```
using IDESK.Models.UserMaster;
using IDESK.Models;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing;
using IDESK.Models.Customer;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Office2021.PowerPoint.Comment;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

namespace IDESK.Controllers.UserMaster
{
    public class UserRightsController : Controller
    {
        private readonly DbConn _dbConn;
        public static List<User_Auth> user_auth = new();
        public static List<ModuleMaster> moduleMasters = new();
        public UserRightsController(DbConn db)
        {
            _dbConn = db;
        }
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        public IActionResult Auth_List(string id)
        { 
            try
            {
                DDLUserList();
                //var ListItem = _dbConn.Modules.ToList(); //--for single table



                // var ListItem = (from i in _dbConn.UserMaster
                //              select new { i.UserId, i.Password,i.UserLevel,
                //              i.UserGroup, i.Mobile_No,i.ConfPassword,
                //              i.Department,i.DisplayName,i.Email,i.IsActive}).ToList();
                //.Distinct()
                //.OrderBy(i => i.category_name);

                var isAjax = Request.Headers["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest";
                if (isAjax)
                {

                    var ModuleList = from a in _dbConn.Modules
                                     from c in _dbConn.UserAuth.Where(c => c.UserId == id)
                                     join b in _dbConn.Module_Group on a.GroupID equals b.GroupID                                  
                                     into modulegroup
                                     from b in modulegroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                     select new ModuleMaster
                                     {
                                         UserId = id,
                                         Module_Group = b.Module_Group,
                                         ModuleID = a.ModuleID,
                                         Module_Name = a.Module_Name,
                                         GroupID = a.GroupID,
                                         IsAccess = a.ModuleID == c.ModuleID ?  c.IsAccess : false,
                                         IsCreate = a.ModuleID == c.ModuleID ? c.IsCreate : false,
                                         IsDelete = a.ModuleID == c.ModuleID ? c.IsDelete : false,
                                         IsEdit = a.ModuleID == c.ModuleID ? c.IsEdit : false,
                                         IsReport = a.ModuleID == c.ModuleID ? c.IsReport : false,
                                         IsView = a.ModuleID == c.ModuleID ? c.IsView : false,
                                     };

                    if(ModuleList.Count() <=0)
                    {
                        ModuleList = from a in _dbConn.Modules
                                         //from c in _dbConn.UserAuth.Where(c => c.UserId == id)
                                         join b in _dbConn.Module_Group on a.GroupID equals b.GroupID
                                         into modulegroup
                                         from b in modulegroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                         select new ModuleMaster
                                         {
                                             UserId = id,
                                             Module_Group = b.Module_Group,
                                             ModuleID = a.ModuleID,
                                             Module_Name = a.Module_Name,
                                             GroupID = a.GroupID,
                                             IsAccess = false,
                                             IsCreate = false,
                                             IsDelete = false,
                                             IsEdit = false,
                                             IsReport = false,
                                             IsView = false,
                                         };
                    }

                    //var ListItem = from a in _dbConn.UserAuth.Where(a => a.UserId == id)
                    //               join b in _dbConn.Modules on a.ModuleID equals b.ModuleID
                    //               join c in _dbConn.UserMaster on a.UserId equals c.UserId
                    //               join d in _dbConn.tblDepartment on c.Dept_ID equals d.Dept_ID
                    //               into user_auth
                    //               from d in user_auth.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    //               select new User_Auth
                    //               {
                    //                   UserId = a.UserId,
                    //                   DisplayName = c.DisplayName,
                    //                   Department = d.Department,
                    //                   ModuleID = a.ModuleID,
                    //                   Module_Name = b.Module_Name,
                    //                   GroupID = b.GroupID,
                    //                   IsAccess = a.IsAccess,
                    //                   IsCreate = a.IsCreate,
                    //                   IsDelete = a.IsDelete,
                    //                   IsEdit = a.IsEdit,
                    //                   IsReport = a.IsReport,
                    //                   IsView = a.IsView
                    //               };

                    return PartialView("_TblUser_Auth_List", ModuleList);

                    //return RedirectToAction("User_Auth_List", ModuleList);
                }
                return View("User_Auth_List", null);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return View();
            }
        }

        //public ActionResult Create()
        //{
        //    DDLUserList();
        //    User_Auth ur = new User_Auth();
        //    return PartialView("_User_Auth", ur);
        //}
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create(IList<ModuleMaster> collection, string action,string UserID) //---Saving data
        { 
            DDLUserList(); //IFormCollection
            return View("User_Auth_List", collection);
        }

       private JsonResult DDLUserList() //--Load Dept dropdown list.
        {
            try
            {
                //var LocList1 = _dbConn.PLANT.Select(cc => new { cc.PLANT_CODE, cc.PLANT_NAME }).Distinct();
                var UserList = _dbConn.UserMaster.Select(x => new
                {
                    Text = String.Format("{0,-10} : {1}", x.UserId, x.DisplayName),
                    Value = x.UserId
                }).ToList();


                ViewBag.UserList = new SelectList(UserList, "Value", "Text");
                return Json(UserList);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Model : ModuleMaster.cs**

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace IDESK.Models.UserMaster
{
    public class ModuleMaster
    {
        [Key] 
        public int ModuleID { get; set; }
        
        [Required]   
        public string Module_Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int GroupID { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "??")]
        [Display(Name = "User ID")]
        public string UserId { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        [Display(Name = "Access")]
        public bool IsAccess { get; set; }
        
        [NotMapped]
        [Display(Name = "Delete")]
        public bool IsDelete { get; set; }
        
        [NotMapped]
        [Display(Name = "Create")]
        public bool IsCreate { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        [Display(Name = "Edit")]
        public bool IsEdit { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        [Display(Name = "View")]
        public bool IsView { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        [Display(Name = "Report")]
        public bool IsReport { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public string Department { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public string Module_Group { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Now I am able to generate the table based on Selectin combo. There are some fields in table which are editable. Unable to pass the entrire table to controller, always shows count=0

I have tried for-loop() instead of ForEach()

Comment: Based on your shared code snippet and descriptions If I am not mistaken, do you want to submit whole table data to controller?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: Have you tried using `asp form` helper method? Are there any specific reason why you are using javascript in your scenario?